# Hashicorp Vault single node

Tags: docker, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to configure a Vault docker container. After initializing and unsealing, I see that the "Active Node Address" is set to `<none>`. Also, when I try run a command I get the following error "local node not active but active cluster node not found". Any help would be much appreciated as I've struggled with this a bit.

**EDIT:**

```
{
  "backend":{
    "consul":{
      "address":"local.consul:9500",
      "path":"vault/"
    }
  },
  "listener":{
    "tcp":{
      "address":"0.0.0.0:8200",
      "tls_disable":1
    }
  },
  "default_lease_ttl": "168h",
  "max_lease_ttl": "0h"
}
```

After unsealing, I try run a vault login, and this is the result
[image]

Comment: Could you provide your Vault configuration file to help understand your problem? Thanks

Comment: It might be a Consul configuration problem. Check this: https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/2890

Comment: I would recommend you to use 0.9.X version of vault. I have spent so much time for debugging the issues with 0.10.1 version and finally downgraded to 0.9.6 version which is stable.